# when we split train and test, we want to give target variable as dynamic

Tags: python, machine-learning

When we try to split with `survived` as target variable it works fine.
But we need it dynamically, without the target variable name. Below is the example which we tried :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split     
def train_test_split(d):
    target='Survived'
    x=d.drop(target,axis=1)
    y=d.target
    x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,
                                        test_size=0.33)
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Cant you use X = d.iloc[:,:-1] and y = d.iloc[:,-1].If you have label as last column

Comment: this works if the target variable is in the last column,but my problem is the target variable is in 2nd column or 4th column or any where

Comment: import random,

foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],

target = random.choice(foo))

Comment: Why not give the columns a list and let it choose randomnly

Answer (score 2):

I hope i have understood your question correctly.

How about making `target` a parameter that needs to be passed to the function like this:

```
   def train_test_split(d, target):
       x=d.drop(target,axis=1)
       y=d.target
       x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.33)
```

You can then pass whatever target value you require e.g `train_test_split(d, "Died")`

Answer (score 1):

I think from what I have understood in your question you just know the index of target column. So just use as below

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split     
def train_test_split(d,i):
    target= d.columns[i]
    x=d.drop(target,axis=1)
    y=d.target
    x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,
                                        test_size=0.33)
```

Pass your required column index into the function

Comment: can you explain me what is 'i'

Comment: 'i' is column number of target variable

Comment: Suppose 'Survived' is in column number 3, pass i as 3.